# How to send a http2 request headers with python socket

Tags: python, sockets, http2, http-1.1

In python:

the http/1.1 request header is :

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

request_header = 'GET {} HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: {}\r\nConnection: close\r\n' \
          'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n\r\n'.format(path, host)

s = s.send(request_header.encode())
```

In my question is , what does the http/2 request_header like?

anyone can help me !! thanks

I've been looking at a lot of resources, but there are no examples of how to create HTTP/2 requests using sockets

Comment: The part about sockets is superfluous.  A socket just sends arbitrary bytes from one end to another.  It doesn't care what those bytes are.  Your question is how to format an HTTP/2 request; you can read the specification here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are interested in stable implementation you could take a look at h2. They have an [example](https://github.com/python-hyper/h2/blob/master/examples/plain_sockets/plain_sockets_client.py) on plain sockets. If you are interested in educational purposes poke around with tcpdump / [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) ([wshrk http2 wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HTTP2)). So you can read how the actual communication looks like in a propper tool, and implement your own version based on the example.

Comment: You could also just curl example with http2 and verbose flags `curl --http2  nghttp2.org/robots.txt --verbose` and take a look at the output.

Comment: Thank you. This h2 example is exactly what I was looking for